# call wxHyperlinkEvent without clicking on link

Tags: c++, hyperlink, wxwidgets

I am using `wxHyperLink`. `OnHyperlinkClicked(wxHyperlinkEvent&)` is called when user clicks on the link. `OnHyperlinkClicked()` helps to switch between 2 screens. I want to call this function explicitly - without user interaction.
I am using the following code for that:

```
BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(UserRegistrationFrame, wxFrame)
EVT_HYPERLINK(wxID_ANY, UserRegistrationFrame::OnAuthCodeOptionLinkClicked)
END_EVENT_TABLE()

void MyClass::MyFunction()
{
    wxHyperlinkEvent event;
    OnAuthCodeOptionLinkClicked(event);
}

void MyClass::OnAuthCodeOptionLinkClicked(wxHyperlinkEvent& event)
{

 // code to switch
}
```

Is this the correct way to achieve my goal? Or do I have to use something different?

Answer (score 1):

The code is **not** correct, because with EVENT_TABLE you are setting a handler that doesn't exist.

When the user clicks on the control the event is fired, and the *static table* will call `UserRegistrationFrame::OnAuthCodeOptionLinkClicked`, not `MyClass::OnAuthCodeOptionLinkClicked`

I'd better forget EVENT_TABLES and go with [Dynamic Event Handling](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/overview_events.html#overview_events_bind). Using `Bind()` gives you more features.

Now, you want to call the event-handler function directly, not coming from a user action. Then you need to create an event just to pass it to the handler. That's what you do in `MyClass::MyFunction()`, right?

Don't mix jobs. If both your direct-call and the event-handler use a common feature, put it in a different function and call it directly or from the event-handler.

But the question is Why do you use a `wxHyperlinkCtrl` for a task like screen switching? Do you want also the default browser to be launched?

Comment: no I don't want default browser to be launched, but I want to display a link to switch between the screens. can I achieve it with some other API?

Comment: Any control sends some type of event. You just need to handle it and do the task there. For your case, why not using a button, or a checkbox? If you don't prefer them, well, wxHyperlinkCtrl still can do the job.